# SparkR - dapply : Can not allocate vector of size x GB

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I am running SparkR using Spark 2.0.1 with 8 cores and ~59 GB memory. While making spark context I have given 25 GB as driver as well as executor memory.

My objective requires dapply to run a particular function over Spark DataFrame, while doing so I am getting following error:

```
Can not allocate vector of size 2.3 GB
```

How can we solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try increasing number of partitions.

Comment: We are already giving the max number of partitions as per the input required by function within dapply

Comment: That error looks may actually be coming from R, and not from Spark runtime. You have to look at the R code (the function) to make sure you are not trying to allocate a large vector.